# Get Child elements through linq to xml

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

How can i get the child element from following xml formatted file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserMenu Type="Company">
  <li>Credit Card Details</li>
  <li>Account Details</li>
  <li>Disc Usage</li>
  <li>Billing</li>
</UserMenu>
```

I want output as:

"Credit Card Details"
"Account Details"
"Disc Usage"
"Billing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var lis = (from e in doc.Descendants("li")
          where e.Parent.Attribute("Type").Value == "Company"
          select e.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you. I got what required. I appreciate it.

Comment: one small question what if i want to add where clause based on UserMenu Type attribute
something like
where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == userType